# Firefox - Web Dev.Tools - Remove Watch Expression

Tags: firefox, web-developer-toolbar

I would like to know how to remove a watch expression from the Web Developer Tools dashboard.
I added a variable name and now I can't remove it.
I tried with:

- right click
- select and delete
- select and backspace
- edit and delete

none of them worked.

Here is screenshot of the watch expression.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hover the mouse over the rightmost end of the watch expression and a tiny [x] button appears — click to delete.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. As you can see in the snapshot it was hidden on the right.